# Calculate DC cable diameter

Tags: voltage, power, dc, watts, specifications

Please assist in defining the required DC cable diameter for the following requirements:

- Voltage: 48 volts
- Watt: 8500 watt
- Running distance: 50 meters

Comment: How much is the voltage allowed to drop?

Comment: You are talking about something like 200 amperes.  That's going to be a very thick cable.

Comment: What temperature are you prepared to allow the cable to rise to when continuously passing 177 amps? What volt-drop is allowable? Are there a forward and return cable to consider?

Comment: let's say 3% drop

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some assumptions, and calculate with 'back of the envelope' grade accuracy.

Assume you want less than 10% voltage drop, let's say to deliver 44 V at the end of the cable, that's 2 V drop on each 50 m out and return conductor.

Round the current to 200 A, so each conductor must be < 10 mΩ resistance.

The room temperature conductivity of copper is about 17 mΩ per metre for 1 mm<sup>2</sup> area. You will therefore need a total area of 50 * 17m / 10m = 84 mm<sup>2</sup>, based on voltage drop.

According to wikipedia's [AWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) page, 85 mm<sup>2</sup> is 000 AWG, which has a 200 A rating, but only if the insulation is rated to 75 °C, and some other assumptions about whether the wires are run singly, or bundled in conduit.

What's the cost of 100 m of 3/0 cable? Or maybe use a larger cross section of (cheaper) aluminium conductor.

Maybe it's time to think about transforming the voltage up, and then down again at the far end, this would dramatically reduce the required area. With an active voltage reducer at the far end, you would also be able to get a constant 48 V regardless of load.

(update) It's worth re-doing the sums for a new assumption, as it illustrates just how sensitive the answer is to them.

Choosing a 3% voltage drop instead of my initial 'less than 10%' means you have to **triple** the cross-sectional area of the copper from 85 mm<sup>2</sup> to 250 ish. On the good side, that means you don't have to worry about ampacity, this cable will not get hot.

If voltage drop really matters, then that's even more incentive to go for distribution at a higher voltage, and convert down to 48 V at the far end. You would get exactly 48 V output at any load, and if you sent around 300 V for instance, your cable requirement drops to single digits (<10) of mm<sup>2</sup>.

48 V is a very convenient voltage to buy converters for, as it's used in many industries, and there will be a good choice of off-the-shelf converters to choose from.

(/update)

Comment: At 3 % allowed voltage drop, that's a whopping 283 mm^2 conductor area needed.

Comment: This in turn works out to about 19mm diameter.

Answer (score 0):

8500 watts / 48 volts = 177 amps

In the united states I reference the Electrical code NFPA 70.  There are several tables in article 310, which list conductor ampacities based on temperature ratings and insulation types.  Tables are also provided for conductors in free air or 3 current carrying conductors in raceway (pipe).  Conductor sizes are listed in American Wire Gauge (AWG).

The free air tables have a higher ampacity.  Higher temperature columns only apply if all components in your installation are rated for the higher temperature, such as lugs and bolted connections.  For this reason I always select the current ratings from the lower temperature columns.

Working from Table 310.15(B)(16) Not more than 3 current carrying conductors in raceway or cable.  From the 75 °C column which groups insulation types such as THHW, THW. THWN ect 3/0 AWG - 85 mm² Cable has a rating of 200 amps and 2/0 AWG - 67.4 mm² Cable has a rating of 175 Amps

If you create an account on nfpa.org you can get free access to the NFPA 70 code without buying the code book.  I am working from an older 2017 version of the code so my references may be off as compared to the 2023 code.